# Legality of screenshot of another website

Tags: links, legal

I wanted to write a blog post about a common feature of some popular websites. To illustrate, I'll need to take screenshot, crop and shows the specific features that's I'm referring to.

I wonder if that's legal? Do I need to inform the webmaster for each of the site before I publish my post?

A second question is that since my focus is that specific feature, so I guess I should blur out the content of the screenshot, or I shouldn't alter anything?

Comment: Regarding blurring out identifying features, you wouldn't have to if it's a publicly accessible website. If you have to be a registered user to view the page you're screenshotting from (and *your* viewers are presumed to possibly not be registered), then that's a little trickier. Better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: @AKTed Good point

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly legal for you to publish screenshots in an article/blog post that is discussing the content of those images. This is considered to be within fair use doctrine under [section 107 of US copyright law](http://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap1.html#10), "Limitations on exclusive rights: Fair use." Here are the four conditions given that determine fair use:

> (1) the purpose and character of the use, including whether such use
>   is of a commercial nature or is for nonprofit educational purposes;
>
> (2) the nature of the copyrighted work;
>
> (3) the amount and substantiality of the portion used in relation to
>   the copyrighted work as a whole; and
>
> (4) the effect of the use upon the potential market for or value of
>   the copyrighted work

So long as you're not trying to make money off of someone else's work, publishing screenshots for discussion is legally protected free speech (national security issues aside, of course).

**Disclaimer: I am not an attorney.**

Comment: You're mostly correct, but even commercial uses can be considered fair use. For example, a commercial web blog or online magazine / news site can  still claim fair use when they include a screen shot in an article. The author is being paid to write the article, and the article itself is being used to generate ad revenue for the site. It's still fair use though.

Comment: So, in summary, I don't need to inform the webmaster?

Comment: No, you don't need to do that at all. You're covered by fair use.

Comment: @Lèse majesté Good point, but the parties in question in your example are being paid to comment about the original item. It's very similar to a movie review. When I said, "make money off of someone else's work," I meant it in the narrower sense of trying to sell the original content itself, not making commentary on that content.

Comment: In all honesty, this MAY apply to the United States. I highly doubt it though. If you screenshot copyrighted material (and a website is also copyrighted) you are de-facto infringing the creators copyright. Fair use or not, fair use also implies you are doing your best to inform the third party that you are using the material. Think of the following scenario: You screenshot apple.com's homepage. I doubt their lawyers deems your screenshot as fair use...
DISCLAIMER: I am not an attorney.

Comment: @DKOATED — I'm not aware of any requirement to inform the copyright holder of source material when that material is being used under fair use provisions. Can you quote the relevant section of the law or case history?

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I can't. I'm not a lawyer. In Germany at least, there is no fair use for copyrighted material. You are simply not allowed to copy/reproduce/screenshot/or in any other way make available information that you didn't create yourself. There are exceptions where you are allowed to quote small excerpts of text with correct information about the original author (and thats for private use, non-commercial use only). And still then, you should make an effort to get a waiver or licence from the original creator.
Of course, if the material has an appropriate licence, you can go for it.

Comment: " If you screenshot copyrighted material (and a website is also copyrighted) you are de-facto infringing the creators copyright. Fair use or not, fair use also implies you are doing your best to inform the third party that you are using the material. "

Wrong

Comment: @DKOATED What do you mean it "MAY" apply to the United States. This is US law.

Comment: "In Germany...[y]ou are simply not allowed to...make available information that you didn't create yourself."

Obviously untrue. There would be no news or movie reviews if this were true.

Comment: this is where you err. news and movies reviews are created and written by an author and are not copy/pasted from another source, neither are the images used unlicensed or without approvement.

Comment: @Kenzo I said "MAY" because it may be so, I just can't believe that due to the copyright laws in effect. Also the initial question did not limit the answers to only apply for the United States. Facebook is a US company, true, still they get sued in other countries, because they are breaking other countries laws. Just a quick reminder. The internet is not only limited to the united states ...

Comment: @DKOATED I'm not in the United States myself, so I'm well aware of that.

Comment: @Kenzo Ok sounds good. Look your answer already answered the questions, so I refrained from creating an additional answer. On second thought your points are perfectly valid. I am just a sceptic, since your answer ("So long as you're not trying to make money off of someone else's work, publishing screenshots for discussion is legally protected free speech") may lead some people of thinking, "to screenshot 255 pages of the bestselling book or screenshot the latest movie frame by frame and publish it on my blog for 'discussion'"... which is of course NOT legal ... As I said, I'm no attorney.

Answer (score 2):

Fair use works in USA and every other country that has signed [Berne Convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention) (Every European country has signed it).
It basicly means you can use screenshots in educational purposes and in blog posts with critical reviews of the site.
I have contacted some of the "big" sites asking their written permission to use screenshots for a blog that will be educational (FAIR USE) and also a part of a commercial site (NOT FAIR USE?) and their answer was as expected: "We don't allow the use of our site for commercial purposes."

These sites [Terms and conditions](http://www.tripadvisor.com/pages/terms.html) state that we aren't allowed to copy and distribute their software, page headers, custom graphics, button icons and scripts without their permission..

Lawyer I contacted believes we are not breaking the law if we use screenshots of site available to public (non registered users).

Still not sure what this means for my blog as it is in the grey area of Fair use. For now I will not use screenshots for my blog as it is a part of a commercial site.

If anyone had similar experience and has come to a better solution i would appreciate any info.

**Disclaimer: I am not an attorney.**